# python CGI variable json

Tags: python, json

I need to show uploaded file size in JSON format on Python.
Here is my code:

```
def save_uploaded_file (form_field, upload_dir):

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    if not form.has_key(form_field): print 0; return
    fileitem = form[form_field]
    if not fileitem.file: print 0; return
    varfilepath = os.path.join(upload_dir, fileitem.filename)
    fout = file (varfilepath, 'wb')
    while 1:
        chunk = fileitem.file.read(100000)
        if not chunk: break
        fout.write (chunk)
    fout.close()
    varfilesize = os.path.getsize(varfilepath)
    data['filesize'] = varfilesize
    print simplejson.dumps(data)

save_uploaded_file ("file_1", UPLOAD_DIR)
```

But I got error:

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: global name 'data' is not defined 
      args = ("global name 'data' is not defined",) 
      message = "global name 'data' is not defined"
```

Comment: What is `data`? Where does it come from?

Comment: I want to create a array named data then give a key filesize.

Comment: I am using Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create the map `data`:

```
data = {'filesize': varfilesize}
```